# Qt application stack overflow exception

Tags: qt, qnetworkreply

I want to call `QNetworkReply::readAll` as shown in `Foo()` such that once it completes, another time it should be called.

```
    QString Foo (QString& requestUrl)
    {
       QNetworkReply *pReply = NetManager::getManager()->get(requestUrl,NULL,NULL);
       QEventLoop loop;
       QObject::connect(pReply,SIGNAL(finished()),&loop,SLOT(quit()));
       loop.exec();
       return pReply->readAll();
   }
```

I want this because my Qt Gui application crashed with `0xC00000FD: Stack overflow exception`. and in callstack, I got repeated calling of functions as shown in below callstack.

I don't understand that despite of using `QEventLoop` to make call to `readAll()` synchronous, how recursion is possible.

My Gui application is used by user to click and initiate `readAll()`.

Is there a way to prevent the crash?

```
MyUtility.dll!Class::Function(l) Line abc   C++
Qt5Core.dll!0000000052b0991c()  Unknown
Qt5Widgets.dll!0000000056ff9d9a()   Unknown
Qt5Widgets.dll!0000000056ffb4ff()   Unknown
Qt5Widgets.dll!00000000570e8c57()   Unknown
Qt5Core.dll!0000000052aeb905()  Unknown
Qt5Widgets.dll!0000000056fd4ff2()   Unknown
Qt5Widgets.dll!0000000056fd35a6()   Unknown
Qt5Core.dll!0000000052ae9aea()  Unknown
Qt5Widgets.dll!0000000057021e95()   Unknown
Qt5Widgets.dll!00000000570204ee()   Unknown
Qt5Widgets.dll!0000000056fd5006()   Unknown
Qt5Widgets.dll!0000000056fd4623()   Unknown
Qt5Core.dll!0000000052ae9aea()  Unknown
Qt5Gui.dll!000007fededd3c52()   Unknown
Qt5Gui.dll!000007fededd5f67()   Unknown
Qt5Gui.dll!000007fededc379e()   Unknown
Qt5Core.dll!0000000052b2e6c5()  Unknown
user32.dll!UserCallWinProcCheckWow()    Unknown
user32.dll!DispatchMessageWorker()  Unknown
Qt5Core.dll!0000000052b2ddfc()  Unknown
qwindows.dll!000007fedd1df491() Unknown
Qt5Core.dll!0000000052ae6c61()  Unknown
MyUtility.dll!Class::Function(l) Line abc   C++
Qt5Core.dll!0000000052b0991c()  Unknown
Qt5Widgets.dll!0000000056ff9d9a()   Unknown
Qt5Widgets.dll!0000000056ffb4ff()   Unknown
Qt5Widgets.dll!00000000570e8c57()   Unknown
Qt5Core.dll!0000000052aeb905()  Unknown
Qt5Widgets.dll!0000000056fd4ff2()   Unknown
Qt5Widgets.dll!0000000056fd35a6()   Unknown
Qt5Core.dll!0000000052ae9aea()  Unknown
Qt5Widgets.dll!0000000057021e95()   Unknown
Qt5Widgets.dll!00000000570204ee()   Unknown
Qt5Widgets.dll!0000000056fd5006()   Unknown
Qt5Widgets.dll!0000000056fd4623()   Unknown
Qt5Core.dll!0000000052ae9aea()  Unknown
Qt5Gui.dll!000007fededd3c52()   Unknown
Qt5Gui.dll!000007fededd5f67()   Unknown
Qt5Gui.dll!000007fededc379e()   Unknown
Qt5Core.dll!0000000052b2e6c5()  Unknown
user32.dll!UserCallWinProcCheckWow()    Unknown
user32.dll!DispatchMessageWorker()  Unknown
Qt5Core.dll!0000000052b2ddfc()  Unknown
qwindows.dll!000007fedd1df491() Unknown
Qt5Core.dll!0000000052ae6c61()  Unknown
Qt5Core.dll!0000000052ae8d39()  Unknown
MyUtility.exe!main(int argc, char * * argv) Line abc    C++
MyUtility.exe!WinMain() C++
```

Comment: You haven't shared your code, we can't read your mind to conclude what have you done wrong. Please read [these](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) [pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) from the help center to ask a better question next time. Anyway, I can guess that you have run into an error similar to the one explained [here](https://wiki.qt.io/Threads_Events_QObjects#Forcing_event_dispatching).

Comment: You must provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The little code that shows is insufficient to help you, and as I see you already have 4 votes to be closed the question.

Comment: what is `NetManager`?

Comment: `readAll()` return QByteArray no QString.

Comment: @eyllanesc should not be a problem since `QString` has implicit `QString::QString(const QByteArray &ba)` constructor.